# Flutter Update 2.0.6 Issues with previous libraries like Expanded , ListView, etc

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Recently I have updated my flutter to 2.0.6 version which it says its the latest version. But it shows lots of errors on my project for example I was using `ListView.builder(builder: ...)` but it shows error for `builder` or I used to use `Expanded(child: ...)` but again it shows error on `child`.

I would appreciate if somebody help me solve this problem because my project is large project and its pretty mind-blowing to correct them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `ListView.builder`, instead of using `builder`, just use `itembuilder`.

But `Expanded` widget is working for me, maybe you can share some snippet of your code where you used `Expanded`, and the paste the highlighted error that you are getting.

Comment: I know that, but there are over 100 files to be corrected so its very time consuming. I was looking for a way to do it programmatically but unfortunately I think that there isn’t anyway

Comment: @AlexanderBrandt I know bro, they just completely change whole syntax very frequently, and that is very embarrassing. But I want to know how expanded is giving you error with child? It i not giving me an error. Maybe you can refactor code on every page, it will reduce some amount of work at least.